# Why is some of my code on ActionListener skipped?

Tags: java, sockets, actionlistener

I am doing a project about chatting application. I'm using sockets.  I'm creating this JFrame that gives me the option to connect as a server or a client. When I run my Options JFrame (choose to run as server or client) and I press server button some of my code gets skipped in the action listener. I already spend hours debugging and I don't know why some of my code gets skipped.

```
private void serverBtnMtd() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Running server Method");//Testing
            MyServer myServer = new MyServer();//server gets Created and shows up
            myServer.initializeServer();//Skipped
            myServer.setVisible(true);//Skipped
            System.out.println("End Running server Method");//Testing
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Action listener

```
btnServer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                serverBtnMtd();

            }
        });
```

My Main Method

```
public class MyMain {
    public static void main(String args[])  {
        ServerOrClient mainApp = new ServerOrClient();
        mainApp.setVisible(true);
        mainApp.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

When I run my server class without the options JFrame everything runs. All of the skipping of code happens on the Action listener. I did some println's to test if all my code gets run and only the "Running server Method" shows up in my command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server generally have infinite loops. So your code isn't skipped, just the new MyServer thing doesn't finish to resume your code. Put the code in a new thread.

Comment: Thanks creating a new thread solved my problem. Spending hours debugging was a waste of time. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
setFocusable(true);
```

to your constructor

Comment: the setFocusable(true) doesn't solve my problem. Can you please explain why are you suggesting this

Comment: Did you put it in the constructor? You can't use key and mouse listeners if focusable is false.

Comment: I did but my problem was not solved. Thanks for the heads up. Creating a new thread solved my problem just like mhyst suggested.

Comment: Okay. I'm sorry I wasn't of help, although it is still good to get in the habit of adding this to your constructor whenever you use a jpanel.